# GoogleSignInClient connects only when app's installed from Google Store

Tags: android, service, apk

I am developing an Android game and currently trying to integrate with Google Play Game Services. I got stuck at the sign-on feature.

I use `GoogleSignIn`, `getIntent`, `startActivityForResult` etc. - all as described in Google manual. I think all's setup correctly, because when I build the app, deploy to Google Store (Internal Tests), and then I install it from there, all looks good: `onActivityResult` is called with `result.isSuccess()==true and GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount returns != null`.

The problem is when I try to run the app from Android Studio (or install APK manually). In this case, `onActivityResult` is called with SIGN_IN_REQUIRED and `getLastSignedInAccount` is always null. I am pretty sure all's setup fine (APK is signed, Android Studio is configured to sign the APKs etc.).

To ensure it's not about my Android Studio setup, I have installed manually exactly the same APK which I uploaded to Google Store but again - result is the same. When installed from Google Store, it's OK, when installed manually it's not (again: exactly the same APK binary).

Can you please help me? Theoretically I could continue development, but each I'd like to test something I'd need to upload new version to Google Store...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...its usual DEVELOPER ERROR, what you can do it..add your SHA1 code on firebase console, and it will work, it is showing this behaviour caus your signed key SHA1 is already added, that why it is working on release build and not on debug build, add your systems SHA1

How to get SHA1?

usually right side of android studio have a bar which says **gradle** click on it, expand it got to **app>Tasks>android>signing report** double click it...it will give you your SHA1, paste it on firebase console, wait for 1-2 minutes and check. It will work.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "paste it on firebase console"? I did get the SHA1 as you described but not sure what to do with it.

Also - not sure if it's important, but - when I go to Google Play Console\Game Services\MyGame, I can see my game is linked - there's OAuth2 number generated and application ID too (and the number is pasted in AndroidManifest in my project)

Comment: open your firebase console...go to your app...in settings scroll a bit...you will get a section where edit field is there..there you can paste it